# Problems while using Crystal Reports in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have created reports using Crystal Reports in my asp.net application(vb). It was fine. But when I run it in another system, the report loading fails. So I modified my code like this.

```
sub Loadreport()
try
Dim sreport as new ReportDocument
sreport.Load(Server.MapPath("ClientList.rpt"))
sreport.FileName=Server.MapPath("ClientList.rpt")

catch(ex.exception)

end try
End sub
```

When the control comes to the line:-

```
sreport.Load(Server.MapPath("ClientList.rpt"))
```

it jumps to the catch block showing "Invalid Report path". But initially, the code was not showing any error. I haven't changed the path. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the path to the trace file or an error log or reponse.write it and see if the path on the "other system" is the correct path where the ClientList.rpt is stored.